# Matlab all() functions row numbers

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

I have a matrix and I wanted to find all non-zero rows in the matrix and the `all(A, 2)` function did this but I was wondering if there is a way to list the corresponding row number alongside the value?

Comment: Does `find(all(A,2))` do what you want?

Comment: Yep that worked thanks, I had tried find() on it's own but not with all(). Did you want to post an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `find(all(A,2)`. `all(A,2)` gives you a vector with a 1 where there is a row of ones, and a 0 otherwise. `find` gives you the indices of non-zeros elements of an array. Putting them together gives the required result:

```
A=[0 0 1 0
   1 1 1 1
   0 1 1 0
   0 1 0 1]

find(all(A,2))=2
```